# How to test if my model able to read json

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

So i have this json

```
{"err":1,"message":"MESSAGE"}
```

and i have this class

```
class Users {
  final int err;
  final String message;
  final String userInfo;

  Users({this.err, this.message, this.userInfo});

  factory Users.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Users(
      err: json['err'],
      message: json['message'],
      userInfo: json['title'],
    );
  }
}
```

i want to do a simple test from my json, so i do this

```
group('api_request', () {
 

    test('Format JSON Login Valid', () async {
      expect(await login(), isA<Users>());
    });
  });
```

the result is passed, but when i change my json to this

```
{"err2":1,"message2":"My Custom Message"}
```

the result is still right. So my question is, how can i make the test result to failed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test JSON you have changed the key name to `err2` and `message2` which means you won't get any data in your model class in `err` and `message` field.

```
    return Users(
      err: json['err'], // it will be null
      message: json['message'], // it will be null
      userInfo: json['title'], // it will be null
    );
```

So you can check for null in those fields